# Joystick in HUD layer

Tags: joystick, hud

I want to give the image a joystick to HUD.

The HUD file I have:

```
myJoystick = [CCJoyStick initWithBallRadius: 25 MoveAreaRadius: 65 isFollowTouch: NO isCanVisible: YES isAutoHide: NO hasAnimation: YES];
         [myJoystick setBallTexture: @ "joystick_control.png"];
         [myJoystick setDockTexture: @ "joystick_lid.png"];
         [myJoystick setHitAreaWithRadius: 100];
        
         myJoystick.position = ccp (100,100);
         myJoystick.scale = 0.3;
         myJoystick.delegate = self;
         [self addChild: myJoystick of: 5];
```

and in HelloWorldLayer:

```
(Void) onCCJoyStickUpdate (CCNode *) sender Angle: (float) Angle Direction: (CGPoint) direction Power: (float) power {
     if (sender == myJoystick) {
         spider2.rotation =-angle;
         ...
```

myJoystick not found.
How do I fix this?

This is my code:
[Link](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/1497391/tile%203.zip)

Comment: Which language and platform is this?